# Openxml 2.0 xml processing

Tags: c#, openxml, presentationml

I have a pretty basic question regarding the openxml sdk. I want to process pptx documents.

In my c# code from slideMaster1.xml I want to get a list of every XMLNode where the node's type is p:cNvPr because i want to store their values in a list of strings.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoltan,
The 'p:cNvPr' nodes are Non-Visual Drawing Properties which specifies non-visual canvas properties.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc865246.aspx) for more details.

I wrote a small windows forms app that will open a power point and display the name attributes for all of the non-visual drawing properties for all of the layouts in the Master using the sdk.  Please see screen shot below and [link for zip of the Solution](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb149a9643b330a1&resid=EB149A9643B330A1!144&parid=EB149A9643B330A1!128&authkey=!AASQubPnD2gtvGY).

[image]

The code basically does the following:

```
foreach (var slideMasterPart in PresentationPart.SlideMasterParts)
{
    foreach (var layouts in slideMasterPart.SlideLayoutParts)
    {
    get each of the layouts.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Descendants<NonVisualDrawingProperties>();
                and put the name attribute to the grid.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think LinqToXml can handle that without openxml.

```
string[] values = XElement.Load("slideMaster1.xml")
                       .Descendants("p:cNvPr")
                       .Select(x => (string)x)
                       .ToArray();
```

It may cough on the `p:` as I'm not sure how it'll handle the namespace.  If you give a sample of your xml, I could test it.

Comment: I don't want to unzip the pptx myself because openxml does that for me (i know, it may sound stupid from me) and that's why i would prefer to do it using the sdk